# Changing the number of validations displayed

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a form with multiple fields that are required. Now when I try to save the form and leave it as blank, a validation is displayed.

[image]

The validation is correct. However, I have more than 3 input fields that are required. I want to display them all at the same time. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found where it can be changed. This is under the Save function. I attached the code below: I just need to change the condition in the for loop from 3 to any number I want.

```
// Push up to three validation messages out to the user.
        for ($i = 0, $n = count($errors); $i < $n && $i < 3; $i++)
        {
        if ($errors[$i] instanceof Exception)
        {
        $app->enqueueMessage($errors[$i]->getMessage(), 'warning');
        }
        else
        {
        $app->enqueueMessage($errors[$i], 'warning');
        }
        }
```